# How do I access javascript object by specifying a condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Below is my javascript array object. How do you access the `array[0]` object by using `abbr="CEO"` condition ( I need all values of the object ex: name, image, designation)

```
var leadership = [
                {
                    name: "Peter Pan",
                    image: 'images/alberto.png',
                    designation: "Chief Epicurious Officer",
                    abbr: "CEO"
},
                    name: "Dhanasekaran Witherspoon",
                    image: 'images/alberto.png',
                    designation: "Chief Food Officer",
                    abbr: "CFO"
}]
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function of an array.

```
var filtered = leadership.filter(function(val){
 return val.abbr==="CEO";
});
```